# Elementos em comum entre listas

Tags: python, lista

Como eu faço pra comparar elementos de 2 listas, e retornar a quantidade de elementos em comum ?
Por exemplo:

```
a=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
b=[6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2, 11, 22]
```

Isso deve retornar 2, porque só há 2 elementos em comum.

Comment: As listas podem contem elementos duplicados? Isto é, sem houverem dois números 1 em `a` e `b`, deve ser contabilizado uma ou duas vezes?

Answer (score 2):

Basta fazer a intersecção das duas listas e depois ver o número de elementos.

```
comum=len(set(a).intersection(b))
```

Answer (score 2):

Defina uma variável **num_repetido** com valor **0** que servirá como contador:
`>>> num_repetido = 0`

Faça um loop na lista a verificando se algum dos números se repetem e então adicione na variável num_repetido:

```
 for num in a:
  if num in b:
   num_repetido += 1
```

E por último imprima na tela o valor final da variável **num_repetido**:
`>>> print(num_repetido)`

Vale ressaltar que existem diversas maneiras de fazer isso, como o amigo acima colocou, tudo depende do que você precisa. Abraço.